# Using APEX variable to preview an image in visualforce page

Tags: apex, visualforce, images

I am trying to preview an apex:image in a visualforce page, which is going to be specified among this apex variable and taken from the static resources.

Here is my code

```
public sObject Object_A {set; get;}
Object_A = [SELECT Icon__c, ........];
```

Visualforce code

```
<apex:image url="{!URLFOR($Resource.Apex_Icons,'{!Object_A.Icon__c}.png')}"/>
```

But in this way I cant't get what is `Object_A.Icon__c` contains, instead of that I got an image that's named `{!Object_A.Icon__c}.png`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are already in a Visualforce expression because of the outer `url="{! ... }"` so should able to use simple string concatenation:

```
<apex:image url="{! URLFOR($Resource.Apex_Icons, Object_A.Icon__c + '.png') }"/>
```